# UPD client and UDP server

Tags: c

How can I use different machines to send messages using UPD client and server? I understand that using these two on the same machine, I just need to compile them and messages go through. But with different machines how?

This code is for the UDP client.

```
/*
Simple udp client
Silver Moon (m00n.silv3r@gmail.com)
*/
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<stdlib.h> //exit(0);
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFLEN 512 //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888 //The port on which to send data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
            die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
            printf("Enter message : ");
            gets(message);

            //send the message
            if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
            {
            die("sendto()");
            }

            //receive a reply and print it
            //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
            memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
            //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
            if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
            {
            die("recvfrom()");
            }

            puts(buf);
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is for the UDP server.

```
 /* Simple udp server
 Silver Moon (m00n.silv3r@gmail.com) */
 #include<stdio.h> //printf
 #include<string.h> //memset
#include<stdlib.h> //exit(0);
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#define BUFLEN 512 //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888 //The port on which to listen for incoming data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
 }

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
    die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
            die("bind");
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
            printf("Waiting for data...");
            fflush(stdout);

            //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
            if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct   sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1)
            {
                    die("recvfrom()");
            }

            //print details of the client/peer and the data received
            printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr),
            ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
            printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

            //now reply the client with the same data
            if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
            {
                    die("sendto()");
            }
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the client code, you need to set the IP address of the machine where the server is running.  Your server looks like it should be OK as it is.

Comment: Say something like this: ./udpclient server 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Help, I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Wow! This code uses the *ancient* `struct sockaddr` initialisation form! Why are you learning from this? I suggest learning about `getaddrinfo` before you go any further... It might also be a good idea to note that UDP isn't considered a client/server protocol.

Comment: Just learning how you can send messages using UDP.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a local IP address (assigned to loopback interface see below IP for **lo0** interface). Its good for communicating across difference process acting in client server roles on the same host/system.

What you need is the assigned IP of the primary interface (like eth0/ en0 etc.) on your server system. On a MAC this looks as below

```
#ifconfig -au
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    ..
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ..
    inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

In the above output I'd use the IP address on **en0** which is 192.168.1.2 (for  server to bind) and then the clients can connect to that IP over the network.

Comment: I don't understand this. How did you start with compiling and everything? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: You are already doing a bind on  INADDR_ANY on the server
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); so you should be able to connect by specifying on your client side an IP address of the server (not 127.0.0.1) to connect over the network.

Comment: How? Say my IP address is 123.4.5.6. Do I have to write like ./udpserver localhost 123.4.5.6? I am using a Mac and have another machine that is windows. I want to send messages from Mac to windows or vice versa.

Comment: In your code for the client program you have the following #define SERVER "127.0.0.1" change this to the server's IP because you have a call later to inet_aton that takes ASCII IP and turns that into network byte order format which is later used for communication. Update that and you should be able to connect provided everything else is working.

Comment: Change that into my own IP server? Once that is done I would compile normally?

Comment: Yes it should compile and all should work fine. I just did that on my system and it works fine while connected to non localhost address. Hope this helps